# Q. Does Foursquare API have an option to pass the logo as part of check-in

Tags: foursquare

I am building a mobile app which requires passing app logo (image) into Foursquare. Does Foursquare API have an option to pass the logo of my application to Foursquare as part of the check-in?

ex. Checked in via ABC (logo)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to pass a logo with every check-in, just like there isn't a way to pass in the name of your application.

Instead, you should go to [your developer page](https://foursquare.com/developers/apps) and make sure that you've set the name and icon of your application correctly there. We use that data to attribute photos, check-ins, and other data to your application.